# Beamer arrows to figure certian location

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-arrows

I have the following picture:

[image]

I would like to draw arrow to the cell membrane, to the mitochondrion and to the nuclear envelope and on the other side of the arrow the appropriate cell organell/membrane.

Another important thing is that, the text should be on the right side of the figure

I have tried to do it, but I am stucked.

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (cellMembrane) {};
\node (mitochondrion) {};
\node (nuclearEnvelope) {};
\node (cell) [left=of cellMembrane] {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{pic.png}};


\node (a) [] at (cell.center) {};
\node (b) [] at (cellMembrane.center) {cell membrane};
\node (c) [] at (mitochondrion.center) {mitochondrion};
\node (d) [] at (nuclearEnvelope.center) {nuclear envelope};

\draw [ultra thick,magenta,<-] (a) to (b);
\draw [ultra thick,magenta,<-] (a) to (c);
\draw [ultra thick,magenta,<-] (a) to (d);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

**UPDATE**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-imagelabels}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{annotationimage}{width=6cm}{pic.png}
    \draw[annotation right = {cell membrane at 0.45}, thick, ->] to (0.75,0.45);
    \draw[annotation right = {nuclear envelope at 0.75}, thick, ->] to (0.6,0.64);
\end{annotationimage}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

The problem is that, it add a white border or someting like that around the arrow. Other problem is that a "white" circle appears around the arrow

[image]

White circle

[image]

Comment: You might find https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/579177/36296 helpful

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have just updated my question

Comment: With this, few other problems appeard as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As said in comments, the `tikz-imagelabels` package might be helpful.

If you don't like the halo around the arrows, you can disable it like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-imagelabels}

\imagelabelset{
  annotation arrow/.style =
  {
    draw,
    ->,
    black,
    thick,
    shorten >= \borderthickness + \arrowdistance,
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{annotationimage}{width=6cm}{example-image-duck}
    \draw[annotation right = {with pizza at 0.45}] to (0.75,0.45);
    \draw[annotation right = {Cute duck at 0.75}] to (0.6,0.64);
\end{annotationimage}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that what I wanted

Comment: @pal99 You're welcome!